# Angular material table not showing the values

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some data which i need to display in a table but its not showing. When i am showing in other element its showing but not in table.

My code

```
    <mat-accordion *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            {{post.name}}
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <p>{{ post.type}}</p>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
    
    
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="posts" class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
    
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.company}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.type}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantity </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.quantity}} </td>
  </ng-container>

</table>

    <p *ngIf="posts.length == 0" class="info-text mat-body-1">No Reccord added yet</p>
```

You can see i have mat-accordion first then i have a table records are showing in mat-accordion but not in this table i am doing any mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer is right but

You need to add

```
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

and also in the .ts file define your columns

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'company', 'type', 'quantity'];
```

You can see documentation also for help but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In the above example table rows information is missing.

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

displayedColumns should be array of columns to be shown.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview